# Get Shopify Product ID from New Inserted Mysql Product PHP Shopify

Tags: php, shopify

I have a list of products in a mysql table. From this list, I can add each product to my Shopify store. How can I get the newly generated Shopify Product ID so I can associate that Shopify Product ID with the product in my database?

Answer (score 0):

See this article: [Where do I find my variant ID?](http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/products/where-do-i-find-my-variant-id)

Given a product page:

> ```
> http://my-shop-name.myshopify.com/admin/products/my-product
> ```

Add ".xml" or ".json" to the end of the URL:

> ```
> http://my-shop-name.myshopify.com/admin/products/my-product.xml
> ```
>
> ```
> http://my-shop-name.myshopify.com/admin/products/my-product.json
> ```

The XML/JSON data contains all the info for your product, including the product id.

Comment: XML is being phased out (thanks be to whatever god governs things), so best to use JSON. It is so much nicer anyway. XML for web needs to be relegated to the dustbins of enterprise history.